# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Copying parquet blob to backup blob using snappy compression

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using a Copy Data activity to back up a parquet file in Azure blob storage (source) to another Azure blob storage container (sink). I selected 'snappy' compression for the sink. I am using DefaultIntegrationRuntime (South Central US) - so not self-hosted, meaning I have no control over the environment. I run this on several files at least once a day. Occasionally, I'll get the following error for a source file that is almost 1G in size. There is another source file that is 1.6G in size that never throws the same error.

```
    Code:21000,
    Message:Failure happened on 'Sink' side.
    ErrorCode=ParquetJavaInvocationException,
    '
        Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
        Message=An error occurred when invoking java,
        message: java.lang.OutOfMemory
        Error:Direct buffer memory
        total entry:19
        java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:658)
        java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
        java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
        org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.SnappyCompressor.setInput(SnappyCompressor.java:97)
        org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.NonBlockedCompressorStream.write(NonBlockedCompressorStream.java:48)
        org.apache.parquet.bytes.CapacityByteArrayOutputStream.writeToOutput(CapacityByteArrayOutputStream.java:219)
        org.apache.parquet.bytes.CapacityByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(CapacityByteArrayOutputStream.java:239)
        org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesInput$CapacityBAOSBytesInput.writeAllTo(BytesInput.java:392)
        org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesInput$SequenceBytesIn.writeAllTo(BytesInput.java:283)
        org.apache.parquet.hadoop.CodecFactory$HeapBytesCompressor.compress(CodecFactory.java:165)
        org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ColumnChunkPageWriteStore$ColumnChunkPageWriter.writePage(ColumnChunkPageWriteStore.java:98)
        org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.writePage(ColumnWriterV1.java:148)
        org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.flush(ColumnWriterV1.java:236)
        org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreV1.flush(ColumnWriteStoreV1.java:122)
        org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.flushRowGroupToStore(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:169)
        org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.checkBlockSizeReached(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:143)
        org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.write(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:125)
        org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.write(ParquetWriter.java:292)
        com.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetBatchWriter.addRows(ParquetBatchWriter.java:61)
        .,
        Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.ParquetTransferPlugin,
    '
    '
        Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.JniExt.JavaBridgeException,
        Message=,
        Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.HiveOrcBridge,
    ',
    EventType:0,
    Category:5,
    Data:{FailureInitiator:Sink},
    MsgId:null,
    ExceptionType:null,
    Source:null,
    StackTrace:null,
    InnerEventInfos:[]
```

I tried raising the DIUs to 8, but the runtime only used 4 and I still get the error. How can I debug this?

Comment: I opened a support ticket with MS

Answer (score 0):

From MS Support:

> I am working with ADF Product Group (PG) to find a solution for this
> randomly failing copy activity issue. I have currently opened an
> incident ticket to my ADF PG and they told me that this is a known
> issue which is causing failures intermittently when
> compress/decompress with snappy and sometimes with your data.
>
> So, recently we have released a fix but it is not fully enabled yet in the
> backend...
>
> Our ADF PG has turned on the feature for you. Could you
> please run your job and let me know if you still see any issues.

The error is so intermittent, there have been days in the past before the error occurs. I will report back in a couple weeks with the results.